# Getting number from a prompt and looping

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I want to create a function where I get a number from a prompt and then create a loop where the number I got is the number of time the alert() executes.

I tried like this :

```
function game() {
    var i = prompt("Choose a number");

    for(i; i === 0; i--) {
    alert("ALERT");
    }
}

game();
```

But after I get the prompt(), nothing happens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your for-loop condition is wrong.  Should be i>0, not i===0.

Answer (score 1):

Or...

```
while(i) {
    alert("ALERT");
    i--;
}
```

Zero evaluates as false.